# HP Pavilion 14 won't boot properly

Tags: boot, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, hp-pavilion

When trying to boot my HP pavilion the power button would generally start to blink and it would either  show a black screen with white lines or it would actually boot with white color on the sides of the screen I was told it's probably a problem with my GPU. I have some screenshots of the issue:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 2):

> I was told it's probably a problem with my GPU. I have some
> screenshots of the issue:

The Windows loading circle is evident on the screenshot.

See if it will start in Safe Mode.

More importantly, go to the HP Site for your model and get the HP Hardware Diagnostics on a bootable USB Key.

Test all the hardware to see what component is faulty. HP Hardware Diagnostics are the best way to do this.

Since startup had begun, it also could be a badly corrupted operating system.